# Dart & Flutter: Need help understanding how to capture futures

Tags: object, flutter, dart, future

I am learning Future objects in Dart language and I have been experimenting with them. I want to create an async function containing a future object.
The latter should return a string and the function should return whatever that future returned.
I know I am not so good with words, but here's the code and comments :

```
Future<String> getData(int number) async { // here I created my async function
  // here is my future object assigned to a variable called thisFuture
  Future<String> thisFuture = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    'this is a future string $number.';
  });
  // here, I am returning the future object
  return thisFuture;
}

main(){
// inside my main function, I want to assign the above function to a variable without executing it
Future<String>captureFunc = getData; // I get an error
print(captureFunc(01)).then((e)=> print(e)); // here I want to access the string inside the future object.
// I am expecting to get: this is a future string 01.
}
```

And I get exception:

```
A value of type 'Future<String> Function(int)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<String>'.
This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.
```

Kindly, help me understand how futures, futures inside a function and how to get the get the value from a function containing a future type object.

Comment: try: `Future<String> getData(int number) { return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 'this is a future string $number'); }` amd calli it like this: `print('start');
getData(3).then(print);
print('end');`

Comment: @pskink yes it did, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is creating the error.

```
print(captureFunc(01)).then((e)=> print(e));
```

print is a simple inbuilt function with void return, thus it creates an error. You should call the captureFunc first and use then call back to print the results something like -

```
captureFunc(01).then((e)=> print(e));
```

Also if you wanna avoid using and chaining then callbacks then you can use the async-await with main, since captureFunc return future above code can cleaned as this -

```
Future<String> getData(int number) async {
  var thisFuture = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
    return 'this is a future string $number.';
  });
  return thisFuture;
}

main() async {
  var captureFunc = getData;
  print(await captureFunc(01));
}
```

async-await is just a a declarative way to define asynchronous functions and use their results and it provides syntactic sugar that help you write clean code involving futures.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the solution and more importantly the explanation.
I have a follow-up question, what if I had a second ```Future``` object and wanted to create a list that contains that captures the values of the two objects.
What type should I declare my list?

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are trying to pass a Function that returns a String to a String. And your inner Future in getData is returning nothing. In the main() you are resolving the future with `then` and trying to print it out. Try the code bellow:

```
   Future<String> getData(int number) async { // here I created my async function
      // here is my future object assigned to a variable called thisFuture
      var thisFuture = await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        return 'this is a future string $number.';
      });
      // here, I am returning the future object
      return thisFuture;
    }
    
    main(){
    // inside my main function, I want to assign the above function to a variable without executing it
    var captureFunc = getData; // I get an error
    captureFunc(01).then((e)=> print(e)); // here I want to access the string inside the future object.
    // I am expecting to get: this is a future string 01.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution and more importantly the explanation.
I have a follow-up question, what if I had a second ```Future``` object and wanted to create a list that contains that captures the values of the two objects.
What type should I declare my list?

Comment: If i understood your question, you can declare Future<List> or Future<List<T>> if you want to specifie the type of the objects in the list. By example, you can declare ```Future<List<MyObject>> = await someAsyncFunctionThaReturnsAListOfMyObject()```

Answer (score 1):

Future objects are asynchronous, meaning the program doesn't wait for it to finish when called, so you have to make it either wait for the value returned by using `await` keyword or use a [futurebuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).

So in the code you posted you need to add await before printing the object value. `then` does not work here because it already finished running the program before getData() returns the future object so it never gets called.
You want to modify the code to something like this:

```
main(){
int data = await getData();
print(data);
}
```

For further reading check here:
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await